# SQL query to combine data from 2 tables with pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, pivot

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [ObIndex](
    [idx] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [dtg] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [site] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [lat] [float] NOT NULL,
    [lon] [float] NOT NULL,
    [el] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SurfaceObIndex] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [icao] ASC,
    [dtg] ASC
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE [ObData](
    [idx] [int] NOT NULL,
    [label] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [value] [varchar](128) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SurfaceObData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [idx] ASC,
    [label] ASC
)
```

where for each record in ObIndex there will exist one or more records in ObData, each containing a single parameter from the observation (note that stations may have different instruments):

```
ObIndex (metadata)
    1,"2017-11-15 12:00:00","C104","AWS 104",-77.100,-167.100,33
    2,"2017-11-15 12:00:00","C105","AWS 105",-77.200,-167.200,55
    etc.

ObData (instrument data)
    1,"Temperature", -10
    1,"DewPoint", -20
    1,"WindDirection", 123
    1,"WindSpeed", 45
    1,"Humidity",66
    2,"Temperature", -10
    2,"DewPoint", -20
    2,"WindDirection", 123
    2,"WindSpeed", 45
    2,"Pressure",998
    etc.
```

There is also a third table of current station locations that is not relevant to this question.

I want to use a single query, if possible, to extract all the values from the ObData table for each ObIndex record, and convert the 'label' values to column names.  This query works for a single observation (or record in ObIndex):

```
select
Min(Case label When 'Temperature' Then value End) Temperature, 
Min(Case label When 'DewPoint' Then value End) DewPoint
Min(Case label When 'WindSpeed' Then value End) WindSpeed, 
Min(Case label When 'WindDirection' Then value End) WindDirection, 
From SurfaceObData Where SurfaceObData.idx = 138586
```

Can anyone help me complete the query to return data from all observations?
The results would ideally look like:

```
idx,site,dtg,WindDirection,WindSpeed,Temperature,Humidity,Dewpoint,Pressure
1,"C104",2017-11-15 12:00:00,123,45,-10,66,-20,
2,"C106",2017-11-15 12:00:00,123,45,-10,,-20,998
```

(Not sure how to put it in table format... First post.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

just group by the `SurfaceObData.idx` column

```
select SurfaceObData.idx,
       Min(Case label When 'Temperature' Then value End) Temperature, 
       Min(Case label When 'DewPoint' Then value End) DewPoint
       Min(Case label When 'WindSpeed' Then value End) WindSpeed, 
       Min(Case label When 'WindDirection' Then value End) WindDirection, 
From   SurfaceObData
Group By SurfaceObData.idx
```

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you!  So Simple... But, I can see that I did not make it clear that I would also like to have the metadata from the observation (Site and Date at least).

Comment: how would the expected result looks like ?

Comment: btw, I gave your answer a +1 but it doesn't show because of my low status.  Thanks again!

Comment: it is ok. no worries.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the assist from Squirrel I found the solution:

```
select i.idx,i.site,i.dtg,
    Min(Case d.label When 'WindDirection' Then d.value End) WindDirection, 
    Min(Case d.label When 'WindSpeed' Then d.value End) WindSpeedKnots, 
    Min(Case d.label When 'Temperature' Then d.value End) Temperature, 
    Min(Case d.label When 'Humidity' Then d.value End) Humidity,
    Min(Case d.label When 'DewPoint' Then d.value End) DewPoint,
    Min(Case d.label When 'Pressure' Then d.value End) Pressure
    from SurfaceObData  as d, SurfaceObIndex as i 
    where d.idx = i.idx
    group by i.idx,i.site,i.dtg
```